# how to have a single activity class for many Image Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a footer in all the layouts for a android application.
The footer will have Image buttons like "Help", "Home", this Image buttons directly link to Help class and Home class.
Can I have a one single activity class for all the footer Image buttons.
I tried with

```
public class FooterItems extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.footerBtnHome)
     { 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
       return;
     }

     if(view.getId() == R.id.footerBtnFeedback)
     { 
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Feedback.class);
         startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
       return;
     }      
   }
}
```

but I am not getting how to call these in a class... for example the project is having  MainActivity class in which I have

```
 ImageButton buttonFeedback = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFeedback);
    buttonFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Feedback.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
    });
```

When I call Feedback.class with onClick from one Image Button... layout and same footer items appears.
I want to use the generalised FooterItems class so I can have one class for footer and use in every other layout.
I am also using  android:onClick="onClick" in xml for Image Buttons for footer only.
But how to call those generalised class FooterItems and make it work.
Looking forward to the reply.
thanks.

[image: Footer image]

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest another variant:
I think, you can add to XML android:onClick, for example:

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

And when user click this button, android programm call method selfDistruct. You just have to implement this method. Android tutorial:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: I am sorry. I don't see you answer, when I writing my answer.

Comment: don't mind, but really nice try as you are new SO member, keep rocking as same.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to start an active participate in the discussion of questions)))

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not much clear.

You want to have Help, Home, etc. Image Buttons as common to all layouts in your application correct ?

If you click any Image Button, you have to show the layout on top and these buttons also has to appear on screen??

If yes my answer may help you.

You told i will create footer items as one activity, but its not good. I will prefer ViewFlipper in this case. See the layout.

```
<LinearLayout vertical>
    <ViewFlipper id=vf>
    <include layout1 />
    <include layout2 />
    <include layout3 />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout horizontal>
    <ImageButton button1 />
    <ImageButton button2 />
    <ImageButton button3 />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Initially you will get **layout1 and all image buttons on screen**. If you want to show **layout2 when you click button3** write onClickListener as below.

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.vf);
```

The variable vf is used to change layouts.

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick() {
        vf.setDisplayChild(1);
    }
});
```

I hope it may help you. Bye.

Comment: I have many Image Buttons...in footer and it has home, help and others. what I wanted to ask is rather writing the same code for buttons again and again in different layouts can I make one class for many layouts for footer only.

Comment: can you please post screen shots of your application with different button clicks. a little confusion in question.

Comment: [Mr. Mukunda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/791169/mukunda) my answer gives same output as you require, but i won't use multiple classes as you. All layouts and footer items will be in single class only and many layouts as xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you want to implement Footer view with 2 buttons: Help and Home, this should be at bottom of every activities.

If you want to implement a code for once then follow the below steps:

1. Define a footer layout with 2 buttons, define android:onClick="btnHelp" for help button and android:onClick="btnHome" for home button.
2. Now you can include this layout inside any activities by using `<include>`.
3. Define a base activity with below 2 methods.
4. Now extends this base activity wherever you implements this footer layout.

> ```
> public void btnHelpClick(View v)
> {
>   // do your task for Help
> }
>
> public void btnHomeClick(View v)
> {
>   // do your task for Home
> }
> ```

Comment: I have footer in each and every layout in xml and I am not using include... but what I need is one class for all those buttons appearing in footer, so that coding will be same for all the footer buttons...

Comment: yes the same thing i have mentioned in answer. you have to code for once.

Comment: My dear its clearly written that contains the parent activiy class with two functions, and extends this parent activity wherever you want.